# Why doesn't Azure SQL think that an underscore comes between a space and "ZZZZZ"?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I just found a what I think is a bug in Azure SQL:

The query below, shows results:

`Select * from table where '_'  BETWEEN ' ' AND 'ZZZZZZZ'`,

but in fact, in my understanding and in regular SQL Server or Oracle, this query doesn't show any results.

Any thoughts here?

Comment: It will be collation dependent whether or not that evaluates to `true`

Answer (score 1):

Trailing spaces are disregarded in `=` and `between` comparisons.  So `' '` is equivalent to `''`, which the lowest non-null value in the varchar sort order for the current (and I think every) collation.  This is the same on SQL Server and Azure SQL Database.

In currently in all non-binary collations `'Z' > '_'` and in all binary collations `'Z' < '_'`, but `' '` is always lower.

You can run the comparison in all collations with dynamic SQL.  EG

```
declare c cursor local for select name from fn_helpcollations()
declare @collation sysname

declare @collations table(collation sysname, is_Z_less_than_underscore bit)

open c
fetch next from c into @collation
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
  declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select ''' + @collation + ''', case when ''Z'' < ''_'' collate ' + @collation + ' then 1 else 0 end'
  begin try
    insert into @collations
    exec (@sql)
  end try
  begin catch 
    print error_message()
  end catch
fetch next from c into @collation
end
close c
deallocate c

select *
from @collations
order by 2,1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know in which collations 'Z' < '_' or 'Z' > '_' ?

Comment: See update to answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it helped very much! We are migrating a teradata dwh into azure, and we are facing such issues in some of migrated store procedures. Do you have any idea how can we overcome these difficulties? For example, the issue with the underscore in Teradata didnt return any row, while in Azure it does return. Thanks!

Comment: Teradata and SQL Server both support many different collations.  You need to see which one you are using on Teradata and find a similar one in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks! In Teradata we have ASCII as collation, and in SQL SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. I dont want to change collation at db level, so i tried to changed the query into Select * from table where ('_') collate ASCII  BETWEEN (' ') collate ASCII AND 'ZZZZZZZ' collate ASCII, but it gives me error: Invalid collation 'ASCII'. Please, do you know any way i can fix that query? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It also returns results in MS SQL.
Since '_' in fact seems to be between ' ' and 'ZZZZZZZ' for certain collations, it is actually the same as

```
Select * from table where 1=1
```